# How to plot selected row from datatable in R Studio

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I have a datatable with +2000 rows. Is it possible to select one row and plot it against time

First rows of table:

[image]

To calculate the count (appearances of each element in dataframe) I am using the following code

```
output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
     {
    closed_srs3 %>%
    group_by_(input$buttons) %>%
    summarize(count = n()) %>%
    arrange(desc(count))    
     })
```

from the following dataframe

```
> dput(head(closed_srs3)){

structure(list(Name = c("DASOVOUNIX", "MYSTEGNA_X", "PETROCHORI_SAR", 
"AGNIK_SAR", "GARDIKI-X", "AMOELATOPOS"), Id = c(3311, 1632, 
4779, 4796, 4291, 1449), Date = structure(c(1548892800, 1548892800, 
1548892800, 1548892800, 1548892800, 1548460800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Created = structure(c(1548892800, 
1548892800, 1548892800, 1548892800, 1548892800, 1548460800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Closed = structure(c(1548979200, 1548979200, 
1548979200, 1548979200, 1548979200, 1548979200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))}
```

Comment: Please do not post data as pictures and use a reproducible format instead (e.g. with `dput(your_data)` or `dput(head(your_data))`. How the question is phrased at the moment, you problem is not clear. Can you be more specific please? What du you mean with "select row"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply kath. In my output table i want to show only the name and the count. What i try to achieve is to select one single row and plot the data of that row against time (time=dates from dataframe)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to plot. I don't see numerical values per row.